# Does the Mojave update wipe the previous Apache settings?

Tags: upgrade, apache

I just updated to Mojave over the weekend and today none of my local Apache addresses work, neither `localhost`, nor custom domains.

[image]

I can't find any reference to my previous custom domains in the `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Has Mojave wiped out my previous configuration, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Not sure if it was wiped but I know how to fix.  To make sure I am correct try the alternate HTTP port (8080) so `127.0.0.1:8080`. If that works than you just need to change the port in the apache config. (Also make sure you have started apache `sudo apachectl start`)

Comment: @JBis The Apache service is already running, and no addresses work. Not `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.1:8080`, etc.

Comment: Whats the result of `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`? You can add to your question.

Comment: I have some services listening on `localhost`, but not Apache.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm. Theres nothing listed as running under `httpd` or the user `_www`

Comment: And whats the output of `sudo apachectl configtest` and `sudo apachectl`

Comment: Thanks for that! `httpd: Syntax error on line 545 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so, 10): no suitable image found.`

Comment: And theres your issue! FYI PHP 7 comes preinstalled on Mojave (and High Sierra) `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`. See if you can figure out the issues with those config files and then you can add an answer. If not, we can move to discussion and I can help you further :)